# How to get an access token using Google's OpenID+OAuth hybrid protocol?

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid, php-5.3, gdata-api

I've been spending some time trying to get my web app set up to use this method of authentication, but it really seems like there aren't any examples out there, and the documentation is sparse, seemingly more so in the specific areas I need (Calendar API using OAuth).

Anyhow, I'm stuck on converting the request token I get from google's OpenID+OAuth into a long-lived access token and token secret.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have long lived access tokens + token secrets in OAuth 2.0.

Google's OAuth now gives access tokens (short lived access tokens that can get data from an API) and refresh tokens (you need to persist these tokens, and exchange them for access tokens whenever you need to access user data.)

You have some documentation in these links that you can use - 
i) http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/wiki/OAuth2 
ii) http://code.google.com/p/oauth-php/wiki/ConsumerHowTo - You can find real life examples here about setting up OAuth clients using PHP.

Comment: hi @divyanshm, Thnks for your feedback but above code are not usefull for me because i am using openId of google account to sign in to my application its work fine. but now i want to retrieve my google contact to the my application so i need token for that and token can retrieve using this openID. do u have any idea about that??

Comment: no mate, i don't have much insight on OpenID as such. But you could use only OAuth to achieve all this, that is you can avoid OpenID altogether. If you use pure OAuth flow, that will solve much of your problem.

Comment: no problem at all, I am done with using only oauth with zend framework and also able to retrieve my google contact as wel.but problem is that i need to supply my username and password for that only secretkey and id doesnt work for me. do u know about zend framework?.

Comment: hi @divyanshm, if you want to know  more about openID+oauth this link usefull to u.  https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID.

Comment: its k. You can implement it in any language like php,java,.net etc i am also doing it with php and able to reach at half stage and just need to find how to retrieve a token. if you are doing it and able to find the token pls let me know.. thanks in advanced..